# How to split this line?

Tags: math-mode

The line I want to split is:

```
\begin{equation}
ds^2=-\bigg(\alpha^2 r^2-\frac{4M}{\alpha r}\bigg)dt^2+\bigg(\alpha^2 r^2-\frac{4M}{\alpha r}\bigg)^{-1} dr^2+r^2d\phi^2+\alpha^2r^2dz^2,
%\label{77}
\end{equation}
```

It crosses the page on the left.
How can I split this?

Comment: (1) the tag `splitbib` is useless here (2) the equation fits perfectly in one line (3) this is your fourth question about splitting an equation: you'll get the same answers as in the three previous questions. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: How many line splits do you need: just one, or more than one? please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Package `amsmath` provides lots of environments for splitting math equations, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  ds^2=
  &\;{-}\biggl(\alpha^2 r^2-\frac{4M}{\alpha r}\biggr)dt^2\\
  &+\biggl(\alpha^2 r^2-\frac{4M}{\alpha r}\biggr)^{\!-1} dr^2\\
  &+r^2d\phi^2\\
  &+\alpha^2r^2dz^2,
\end{aligned}
%\label{77}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: minus on first line should be a unary minus.  it's now spaced as a binary minus.  (the result of preceding it directly by the `&`).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. Fixed in updated answer.